# Subpackaging using setuptools does not work in python 3.4

Tags: python, python-3.x, namespaces, package, python-import

I am trying to install a module sub-package `homie.mods.test` into an existing core project's package `homie.mods`.

Therefore I provided both `homie` and `homie.mods` `__init__.py` files with

```
from pkg_resources import declare_namespace
declare_namespace(__name__)
```

within the main project and with

```
from pkgutil import extend_path
__path__ = extend_path(__path__, __name__)
```

within the module.

In their respective `setup.py` I am using `setuptools.setup` with the option

```
namespace_packages=['homie', 'homie.mods'],
```

in both, the main project and the module.

I install the core package first, then the module package.

However I can import any package and module of the core package but not the module's core package.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python 3.4 setuptools namespace setup does not work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34089268/python-3-4-setuptools-namespace-setup-does-not-work)